# What is the fastest way to prepare data for Vector256 in c#

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, simd, unsafe

I'm trying to use SIMD in my function to improve the performance, but it seems like i'm losing more during the data preparation in memory.
What do i have:

```
public class SubProp
{
  public double subProp1, subProp2;
  <few functions>
}

public class MyClass
{
  public subProp prop1, prop2;
  <lots of other props>
}

public void DoSomeMath(List<MyClass> data)
{
  int cnt = data.Count;
  for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
  {
    SubProp Prop1 = data[i].prop1;
    SubProp Prop2 = data[i].prop2
    for(int j = i + 1; j < cnt; j++)
    {
      SubProp Prop3 = data[j].prop1;
      SubProp Prop4 = data[j].prop2;          

      //these substructions suppose to be optimized with SIMD
      double res1 = Prop4.subProp2 - Prop3.subProp2;
      double res2 = Prop1.subProp1 - Prop2.subProp1;
      double res3 = Prop4.subProp1 - Prop3.subProp1;
      double res4 = Prop1.subProp2 - Prop2.subProp2;
      double res5 = Prop4.subProp1 - Prop2.subProp1;
      double res6 = Prop4.subProp2 - Prop2.subProp2;

      <some more math with res<n> variables and logical functions on results>
    }
  }
}
```

What i've already tried:

1. To build Spans of 4 doubles inside the loop (extremly slow)
2. To allocate 3 Spans (left, right for subtraction and 3rd for results) outside the loop as big as stack allows to, and to fill them with numbers inside the loop (pretty slow)
3. To use regular arrays instead of Spans (did see any big difference)

Am i missing something? Some kind of fast way to set data in memory in proper order, or it's not even possible to get a better performance with SIMD in this case?

P.S. A little explanation on how i was expecting to use Vector256 here:

```
var lSide, rSide //prepared arrays or spans
int vectorSize = 256 / 8 / 8;
fixed (double* lptr = lSide)
{
  fixed (double* rptr = rSide)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < array.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize) {
      var lVec = Avx2.LoadVector256(lptr);
      var rVec = Avx2.LoadVector256(rptr);
      resVector = Avx2.Subtract(lVec, rVec);
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.S
It seems like i'm not able to place fields of 2 fields of class one by one in memory:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public sealed class SubProp
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public double subProp1;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public double subProp2;
    public double Sum() //just simple function for the test
    {
        return subProp1 + subProp2;
    }
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public sealed class MyClass
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public SubProp prop1;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public SubProp prop2;
}

MyClass testObj = new MyClass
{
  prop1 = new SubProp
  {
    subProp1 = 10,
    subProp2 = 20
  },
  prop2 = new SubPorp
  {
    subProp1 = 30,
    subProp2 = 40
  }
};

fixed(double* ptr = &testObj.prop1.subProp1)
{
  for(int i=0; i<4; i=i+1)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(*(ptr+i));

  }
}
```

The ouptup is:

```
10
20
0
<garbage>
```

Comment: It looks like you have a contiguous 4 doubles across `subProp prop1, prop2;`.  Are you really trying to use 6 scalar `double` vars, or are you trying to do vector loads from `prop1` and shuffle or blend to get a vector of interleaved subtract results?  Perhaps you want a broadcast load and then subtract, *then* negate some results.  So you can have one vector that's all from `data[i]` and another that's all from `data[j]`.  e.g. isn't `res2` just `-res1`?  You can do that with `vxorps` to flip the sign bit in that element.

Comment: @PeterCordes i was trying to build a datasets for subtruction in order to use them with Avx2.LoadVector256(ptr)

Comment: What's `ptr`?  I'm still not clear if you're doing those subtractions with SIMD (good) or if you're planning to do 6 scalar subtracts and store the results somewhere, then load (probably bad, or at least a store-forwarding stall which has poor latency.  Plus the extra cost of all that scalar work vs. some SIMD shuffles.)

Comment: @PeterCordes i've added a small explanation for you in P.S. section. Hope, it will help

Comment: If the data you want to use SIMD on is separated by "lots of other props" that you want to stride over, you should just use SIMD loads on the data you do want, not copying it into contiguous memory before reloading it.  `Avx2.LoadVector256` can work on 32 bytes of data anywhere, including 2 members of a struct.  (At least in asm, if you can get the compiler to get out of the way and not add a lot of overhead to using it on `data[i].prop1`.  In C++ you could `_mm256_loadu_pd(&data[i].prop1)` to get both properties.

Comment: @PeterCordes now you get the problem right. I'm looking for a fast way to load Vector256 with such separated data. And for now i can't find a way to keep the data in a proper order inside the objects.

Comment: Does C# not let you just use `Avx2.LoadVector256` on `data[i].prop1`, modulo some `fixed` something to keep the compiler happy?  Or I guess that's what you're asking, but for some reason you're also talking about "prepared arrays".  Or even better, can you rearrange your data to a struct-of-arrays layout so you can load a vector of 4 subProp1 elements for `i + 0..3`?  Or do you have too much non-SIMD scalar code that would benefit more from having the props for one `data[i]` be together?  (Or too much code to refactor if you changed that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes `Avx2.LoadVector256` work only with next 256bytes from pointer. `SubProb` have some usefull functions inside itself to work with it's data. It would be easy to restruct it.

Comment: 256 bits = 32 bytes, but yeah that's exactly my point.  Use it on `data[i].prop1` to get a vector of `{ p1.sp1, p1,sp2, p2.sp1, p2.sp2 }` because presumably C# makes `prop1` and `prop2` contiguous.  But restructuring to an SoA format would make your subtractions easier, I think, because then you can vectorize over four `j` values at once instead of doing any shuffling.

Comment: @PeterCordes reading about `StructLayoutAttribute` at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I would have three ideas to optimize your code:

1.: The following two operations:

```
  double res1 = data[i].prop2.subProp2 - data[j].prop1.subProp1;
  double res2 = data[j].prop1.subProp1 - data[i].prop2.subProp2;
```

can be also written as:

```
  double res1 = data[i].prop2.subProp2 - data[j].prop1.subProp1;
  double res2 = res1 * -1; // or double res2 = -res1; Thanks to Peter Cordes for that hint...
```

possible cases:

a = 5, b =  3: a - b = 2 and b - a = -2

a = 3, b =  0: a - b = 3 and b - a = -3

a = 0, b =  0: a - b = 0 and b - a = 0

a = 3, b = -2: a - b = 5 and b - a = -5

Although I must admit, that I don't know if thats faster...

2.: You might make use of Parallel.For instead of your for loop(s). This would be possible, if you do not use the results from one iteration in a following iteration.

3.: You are accessing your properties multiple times. Depending on how often you do this there might be a benefit to locally store them. Especially those accessed by the i counter.

```
for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
  SubProp dataIProp1 = data[i].prop1;
  SubProp dataIProp2 = data[i].prop2;
  for(int j = i + 1; j < cnt; j++)
  {
    //these substructions suppose to be optimized with SIMD
    double res1 = dataIProp2.subProp2 - data[j].prop1.subProp1;
    ...
```

Comment: Will looke more carefull on math, thanks, but my sample has not exactly the same pairs (missed the idea, that it might be important).
About parallel.for. I'm alreay using multithreading there above the function call, thanks.

Comment: Is `res1 * -1` somehow better than the more obvious `-res1`?  You don't actually want it to compiler or JIT to a multiply instruction, rather a `vxorpd` to flip the sign bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I must admit that I don't know what of the two is more performant.

Comment: question was a little bit different from what you're trying to solve, so i've edited all the code to make it exatly the same with a real one. sorry, that i've misslead you a bit

Comment: I'd assume they're equally performant unless the compiler is braindead (or unless some signed-zero semantic reason stops it from optimizing `* -1` into a simple sign flip).  So write it the simple way with unary minus.